# PHP connection to a database (no output!)

Tags: php, html, oracle

I wrote a code to connect a html page to the database, but it does not search for all employees in the table. I'm not sure why the code seems to be correct. It does not give any error or warning.

Can anyone explain to me what is wrong?

```
<div>
  <form id='searchform' action='index.php' method='get'>
    <a href='index.php'>All employees</a> ---
    Search by a last name:
    <input id='search' name='search' type='text' size='20' value='<?php echo @$_GET['search']; ?>' />
    <input id='submit' type='submit' value='Go!' />
  </form>
</div>


<?php
  // check if search view of list view
  if (isset($_GET['search'])) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE LastName like '%" . @$_GET['search'] . "%'";
  } else {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Employee";
  }

  // execute sql statement
  $stmt = oci_parse($conn, $sql);
  oci_execute($stmt);
?>


<table style='border: 1px solid #DDDDDD'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Personal Number</th>
      <th>Insurance Number</th>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Birth Date</th>
      <th>Gender</th>
      <th>Hire Date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
      <th>Office ID</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>


<?php
  // fetch rows of the executed sql query
  while ($row = oci_fetch_assoc($stmt)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['PersonalNumber'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['InsuranceNumber'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['FirstName'] . " " . $row['LastName'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>born on " . $row['BirthDate'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Gender'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>hired on " . $row['HireDate'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Salary'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['OfficeID'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
  }
?>

  </tbody>
  </table>

<div>There are found <?php echo oci_num_rows($stmt); ?> employees!</div>

<?php  oci_free_statement($stmt); ?>

</body>
```

Comment: You're not checking for errors, you're just assuming your queries work. Have a gander at your error logs to see if you see anything there.

Comment: Single quote inside the single quote value='<?php echo @$_GET['search']; ?>'

Comment: You are still open to SQL injections.

Comment: When u open this page u will get the undefined variable search

Comment: and using `@` to suppress errors is bad. it's the coding equivalent of stuffing your fingers in your ears and going "lalalalala can't hear you" - e.g. it's childish.

Comment: You should take a look at what oci_error() return. And you're vulnerable to SQL injection. Which is extra-sad as you're using a statement.

Comment: I get that error -> Notice:  Undefined index: search in index.php on line 27

Comment: Yes, because `$_GET['search']` isn't populated, right? This is pretty similar to your other question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35069568/notice-undefined-index-and-ora-06550-html-php.